# How to store file in database using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to ask you, what is the best way, how to store file in database.

What data typ is best to use?

I try to use `byte[]` but there are a lot of problems with generate database scheme. Annotations for set `mediumblob` not working.

I read a lot of tutorials, but never working! My hibernate always generate `tinyblob`!

Can you help me please?

I am using MySQL.

Comment: have you tried longblob?

Comment: yes, but scheme generate always tinyblob

Comment: can you post the model.

Comment: don't store files in the database

Answer (score 0):

i think you should save your data in a `Blob` which is inside `java.sql.Blob;`
package let's say you have a model like this.

```
import java.sql.Blob;
public class folder{
     public Blob file;

     public Blob getFile() {
        return file;
     }

     public void setFile(Blob file) {
        this.file = file;
     }
}
```

go with below approach, to save the folder object

```
    byte[] FileBytes = //read file and assign to byte array
    folderOb.setFile(photoBytes);//you don't need to set a Blob just pass a byte array
    session.save(folderOb); //saving in the database
```

change your xml mapping to this

`<property name="file" column="file" type="blob" /`>